# how to use Mule SMTP connector with office 365 mailbox to send email ? Also how to use SMTPS in Mule?

Tags: groovy, smtp, mule, office365, starttls

Below is the flow code used for sending mails from office 365 mail account :

Exception received is :
`com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM`

Same account , credentials, Host , port works in groovy script:

```
public static void simpleMail(String from, String password, String to,
    String subject, String body) throws Exception {

    String host = "smtp.office365.com";
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);      
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

    InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);

    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(body);

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    transport.connect(host, from, password);

    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("Mail Sent Successfully");
}
```

as it seems  groovy script has "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" : true, 
"mail.smtp.ssl.trust" : hostname in the script code as property added in it.

So how can i reflect this same using SMTP connector in mule ?

Any suggestion will be greatful.

Comment: below is the Mule Code i have used :

"<flow name="relay">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration_Test" path="/relay" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.office365.com" user="test@orgdomain.com" password="testpwd" to="test@gmail.com" from="test@orgdomain.com" subject="MuleMail" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" port="587"/>
        <logger message="#[&quot;Mail sent SuccessFully&quot;]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
Exception:SMTPSendFailedException Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! 
I suggest you should rather search for your error message, pasted it in Google and there are at least few questions on the StackOverflow - check if any of it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but haven't found any reference with the respect to my above mentioned question.

Comment: How to enable starttls for SMTP connector in mule ?

Answer (score 0):

to enable starttls for SMTP connector, open the email connector, click on advanced tab, click on properties and select inline, then add the key: "mail.smtp.starttls.enable" and set the value = true.